# How can I play videos of a specific youtube channel on my application without the help of browser or youtube application on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here I'm using this code,

```
public class WebTV extends Activity {
WebView mWebView;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webtv);
     mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webTV);
     mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     mWebView.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com/banglanews24");
} }
```

but it'll play the video on the browser directly without showing the channel page on the webview, but instead of that if i use,

```
 mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/banglanews24");
```

it'll show the channel page inside the webView but could not load the or render the videos.
I've also tried,

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/banglanews24")));
```

but none of this work for me.
Can any one give me a solution, through which i can play this youtube channel in side my application, like you tube application for android. **Can any one help me out?**

Comment: This seems like something that would be ruled out by YouTube's terms of use.

Comment: nothing beyond their terms and conditions

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of things in sections 4 & 5 that suggest..  Yup, there *are* restrictions, and your proposed use would violate them.  (Just denying it won't change anything.)